# Derivative of Fourier Transform WRT to Time

Tags: derivatives, fourier-transform, error-propagation

I am looking to take the derivative of the Discrete-Time Fourier Transform with respect to time t. The following is what I have:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}F(\omega) &=\sum_{t=-\infty}^{\infty} {\frac{d}{dt}f(t)e^{-2\pi j\omega t}}\\
&= \sum_{t=-\infty}^{\infty} {f'(t)e^{-2\pi j\omega t}} - 2 \pi j \omega \sum_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}{f(t)e^{-2\pi j\omega t}}\ \text{(by product rule)}\\
&= F[f'(t)] - 2 \pi j \omega F(\omega)\ \text{(using Fourier identity)}\\
&= j\omega F(\omega) - 2 \pi j \omega F(\omega)\ \text{(using time derivative property)}\\
&= F(\omega) [j\omega - 2 \pi j \omega]\ \text{(factor)}
\end{align*}

I don't believe this is proper. From here https://github.com/locuslab/pytorch_fft/issues/4 it's claimed the proper derivative is the Fourier transform of the input gradient, which would be only the first half of my equation under "Using Time Derivative Property". Am I incorrect in my derivation? Is there a reason the 2nd term was dropped?

Comment: Is $\omega$ t dependent?

Comment: Good question, I don't know. I want to say no.

Comment: If it is not is there any reason to use the product rule?

Comment: Yes I forgot a t. I just edited the question.

Comment: Something is wrong with your notation: You sum over $t$ as your index but say that it's your input variable.

Comment: I see what your saying, t is constant and $\omega$ is the input variable here

Comment: You can't take a derivative of a DFT, as a DFT is a set of discrete points, not a continuous function.  Do you want the derivative of the DTFT, or do you want to do something with a discrete time/frequency equivalent of a derivative (first difference, or central difference, or etc.)?

Comment: The derivative of the DTFT.